# Function of Bounded Variation on a closed bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $ f: [-1,1] \to \mathbb {R}$ be a function given by $f(x)= 2x \cos(1/x)+ \sin(1/x)$, if $x \neq 0 $ . Is $f(x)$ a function of bounded variation on $[-1,1]$?

I know a function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb {R}$ is a function of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ if and only if it can be expressed as a difference of two monotonically increasing functions on $[a,b]$. But, I am not getting any hint or idea to this.
I am not getting  whether this function is a bounded variation or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not of a bounded variation. Note, that $f$ is a nice function outside a neighborhood of $0$, so the problem occurs when one approaches $0$.

We can work out our way from the definition of [BV function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#Formal_definition).

For each $k\in \mathbb{N}$ let  $ x_k >0$ be defined from $\frac{1}{x_k} = 2\pi k + \frac{\pi}{2}$. Notice that $x_k \to 0$ as $k \to +\infty$.
We have
$f(x_k) = 1 $ .

Let also $y_k$ be fixed from $\frac{1}{y_k} = 2\pi k $ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Then $f(y_k) = 2 \frac{1}{2\pi k} $.

Now, $y_k > x_k > y_{k+1} $ and if we take a partition (see the definition of  BV function on wikipedia again) of $[-1, 1]$ with alternating $(x_k, y_k) $ points, we'll have
$$
\sum_{i} |f(x_{k_i}) - f(y_{k_i})| = \sum_{i} |1 - 2y_{k_i}| 
$$
which is not bounded above, as $y_k \to 0$ and $k \to \infty$.

Comment: I mean $f,g : [-1,1] \to \mathbb {R}$ are not bounded variations, and $f+g \neq 0$, but $f+g$ is bounded variation.

Comment: well, I don't think you can get anything useful with these sums. Just take $f$ of unbounded variation on [0,1/2], and extend it to [1/2, 1] as identically 1. And then, let $g$ be equal to $ -f$ on $[0,1/2]$ and some nice function on $[1/2; 1]$ (not identically -1). Then $f+g$ has bounded variation, $f+g \neq 0$ and both $f$ and $g$ are of bounded variation. You can make more ``no-trivial " examples, of course.